# How to restore GKE backup of a GKE Cluster from one project to another project's GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, backup

How to restore GKE backup of a GKE Cluster from one project to another project's GKE cluster?

I'm required to move gke backup of a GKE cluster of one project into another project's GKE cluster.

1. I created a backup-plan and a backup in the source project.
2. I also successfully created a restore-plan into target project referencing source project backup-plan and target project's gke cluster through below cloud CLI command.

```
gcloud beta container backup-restore restore-plans create RESTORE_PLAN \
    --project=PROJECT_ID \
    --location=LOCATION \
    --backup-plan=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/BACKUP_LOCATION/backupPlans/BACKUP_PLAN_NAME  \
    --cluster=CLUSTER \
    --namespaced-resource-restore-mode=NAMESPACED_RESOURCE_RESTORE_MODE \
    --all-namespaces \
    --cluster-resource-conflict-policy=CLUSTER_RESOURCE_CONFLICT_POLICY \
    --cluster-resource-scope-selected-group-kinds=CLUSTER_RESOURCE_SCOPE \
    --volume-data-restore-policy=VOLUME_DATA_RESTORE_POLICY
```

3. When we are trying to restore a backup from the source project's GKE backup into the target project's GKE cluster using restore-plan of step 2, we are getting the below error messages.

```
gcloud beta container backup-restore restores create RESTORE \
    --project=PROJECT_ID \
    --location=LOCATION \
    --restore-plan=RESTORE_PLAN \
    --backup=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/backupPlans/BACKUP_PLAN/backups/BACKUP

## Output
Restore execution
Status  Failed  
Status reason   googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'gkebackup.backups.execute' denied on 'projects/67114541833/locations/asia-south1/backupPlans/staging-cluster-backup-1/backups/stg-backup23', forbidden
```

We have added the below permissions to the source project's GKE cluster service account

```
# service-xxxxxx@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Backup for GKE Admin
Backup for GKE Backup Admin
Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
```

We have added the same above permissions to the source project's GKE Backup service account

```
#service-xxxxxx@gcp-sa-gkebackup.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Backup for GKE Admin
Backup for GKE Backup Admin
Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
```

We have added the same above permissions to the target project's GKE Cluster service account

```
# service-xxxxxx@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Backup for GKE Admin
Backup for GKE Backup Admin
Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
```

We have added the same above permissions to the target project's GKE Backup service account

```
#service-xxxxxx@gcp-sa-gkebackup.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Backup for GKE Admin
Backup for GKE Backup Admin
Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
```

What can be done to fix this issue?
What extra permissions need to be added to the service accounts in both projects to achieve this scenario?

Comment: I hope the above information clarifies your queries. If yes, Please consider accepting and upvoting it, which might help the other community members with similar issues. –

Answer (score 0):

### **Updated Solution :**

@devops-admin : After so much analysis and going through this issue  thoroughly I would like to inform you that **it's not possible to restore the GKE Backup from one project to another project**. Also, Backup for GKE is a service for backing up and restoring workloads in GKE clusters within the same project.

**There is already an existing [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270923332) for this issue. Do upvote this Bug Request to get future updates** on this and as of now this is pending with the product engineering team, currently there is no ETA.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it before creating any backups and restores through Google Cloud Console.

Comment: I have added these permissions to target the GKE cluster service account ``` Kubernetes Engine Service Agent``` aka  principal  ```service-845395873@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com```                                                                                             ```Backup for GKE Admin``` ```Backup for GKE Backup Admin``` ```Backup for GKE Restore Admin```
```Google Cloud Managed Identities Backup Admin```
```Kubernetes Engine Service Agent```.

Comment: Same permissions are also added to the source GKE cluster service account. But still, it is failing.

Comment: @devops-admin : Based on the 3rd point as a reference, i observed that you need to give `project=PROJECT_ID` whereas you have given the `Project Number`. Project ID that can be a combination of letters, numbers, and hyphens. We recommend you use the generated project ID. Refer to this document  to [identify the Project ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects). This is also one of the reason for this error.

Comment: @devops-admin : Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue.

Comment: `--backup=projects/api-devops-8459621/locations/asia-south1/backupPlans/staging-cluster-backup-1/backups/stg-backup23` We are giving project_id only for the `--backup` option in that step that `number` is only coming output error message, can't tell how it is substituting project_id with that number.   As of now still it needs to be resolved. Any help in figuring out this issue is  greatly appreciated.

Comment: @devops-admin :  try this syntax `--backup-plan=projects/api-devops-8459621/locations/asia-south1/backupPlans/staging-cluster-backup-1/backups/stg-backup23` . Excute this and let me know the response you are getting. u have missed to given --backup-plan in above comment.

Comment: I tried this way. It failed. It seems that syntax is not supported. Here's complete command. `gcloud beta container backup-restore restores create analytic-restore12 --project=test-analytics-project --location=asia-south1 --restore-plan=analytic-restore-plan --backup-plan=projects/api-devops-8459621/locations/asia-south1/backupPlans/staging-cluster-backup-1/backups/stg-backup23`  . Here response error message.

Comment: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.backup-restore.restores.create) unrecognized arguments: --backup-plan=projects/api-devops-8459621/locations/asia-south1/backupPlans/staging-cluster-backup-1/backups/stg-backup23 (did you mean '--backup'?)`

Comment: No luck as far.

Comment: @devops-admin :  After so much analysis and going through this issue  thoroughly I would like to inform you that `it's not possible to restore the GKE Backup from one project to another project`. Do check my updated answer and `there is also an existing bug, do upvote this Bug Request to get future updates`.

Comment: @devops-admin: I hope the above information clarifies your queries. If yes, Please consider accepting and upvoting it, which might help the other community members with similar issues.